# Merge dictionaries with missing keys to create a combined dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Input is 3 dictionary `d1` / `d2` / `d3`

```
d1 = {aa:1, bb:2, cc:3}

d2 = {aa:9, cc:4, jj:8}

d3 = {aa:5, bb:0, kk:88}
```

Required final

```
final = {aa: [1,9,5], bb: [2,'Not in d2',0], cc: [3,4,'Not in d3'], 
         jj: ['Not in d1',8,''Not in d3'], kk: ['Not in d1','Not in d2',88]}
```

Required is single dictionary with key value as shown below. The position of values should be in order of dictionary.

Also if key is Not in any dictionary then 'Not in d1/d2/d3/... should go in respective position as values. I am able to merge dictionaries but not able to save missing key information as value in final dictioany

Comment: Thanks a lot.. jpp you save my day this is what I am looking for..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to calculate the union of your dictionary keys. Then utilise `dict.get` within a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary mapping keys to lists.

```
keys = set().union(d1, d2, d3)

final = {k: [d1.get(k, 'Not in d1'),
             d2.get(k, 'Not in d2'),
             d3.get(k, 'Not in d3')] for k in keys}

print(final)

{'bb': [2, 'Not in d2', 0],
 'aa': [1, 9, 5],
 'cc': [3, 4, 'Not in d3'],
 'kk': ['Not in d1', 'Not in d2', 88],
 'jj': ['Not in d1', 8, 'Not in d3']}
```